# Flexslider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML slider code:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <div class="large-image">
            <img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/13_2.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="large-image">
            <img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/5_2.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

HTML carousel code:

```
<div class="flexslider flexslider-thumb" id="carousel">
    <ul class="previews-list slides">
        <li><img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/13_2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/5_2.jpg"></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#carousel").flexslider({
    animation:"slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
})
$("#slider").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
})
```

OUTPUT:

[image: all images are displaying as vertically]

all images are displaying as vertically aligned. I want to display it as the slider. How can I do it? and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#slider").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
})
```

This snippet is not targeting any of your html elements. You've got `slides` and `carousel` but `slider` is not in your markup. I'd start there. If that's not it, please post a JSFiddle or Codepen for us...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#carousel").flexslider({
    animation:"slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false
})
$("#slider").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.easing.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://lab.mattvarone.com/projects/jquery/totop/js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script> 
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <div class="large-image">
            <img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/13_2.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="large-image">
            <img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/5_2.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>               
</ul>
<div class="flexslider flexslider-thumb" id="carousel">
    <ul class="previews-list slides">
        <li><img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/13_2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img alt="#" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/698778/5_2.jpg"></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```